# Minimizing the ratio $(a+b)/(a+(a \mod b)$

Tags: number-theory

I ran into the following problem while studying the Euclidean algorithm:

Consider the ratio $\frac{a+b}{b+ (a \mod b)}$ defined for all $a > b$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.

For large $a$, this ratio is unbounded, but what is a tight lower bound for the above ratio? Are there specific values of $a,b$ for which this lower bound is achieved? If not, how do we generate a sequence of $a,b$ to get arbitrarily close to the bound?

I thought that $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ would be the lower bound due to the Fibonacci numbers, but it appears not to be so, since setting $a = 18, b = 10$ we get a ratio $1.55556$ that is even less than $\phi$.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question. The denominator should be $b$ not $a$. Just fixed it.

Comment: Seems obvious that $(2b-1, b)$ is optimal for a given $b$.  That gives $\frac {3b-1}{2b-1}$ which approaches $\frac 32$ in the large $b$ limit.   Needs to be proven of course, but at least this establishes a sequence of values decreasing to $1.5$

Answer (score 1):

It can't be optimal to have $a \ge 2b$, as subtracting $b$ from it would make the numerator smaller while the denominator stays the same. So $b<a < 2b$. Thus we have $a \mod b = a-b$. We are then minimising
$$\frac{a+b}{b+a-b} = \frac{a+b}{a} = 1+\frac{b}{a}$$
subject to $b < a< 2b$. It should be clear this is minimised by making $a$ as close to $2b$ as possible. So $a =2b-1$ when optimising with $b$ fixed.

So the best lower bound is $\inf_{b \in \mathbb{N}^{+}} 1+\frac{b}{2b-1} = \frac{3}{2}$